# AWS Lambda: Append each dictionary to a new line of an Array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, lambda, append

I have an array of Dictionaries in python as shown below, I am iterating over a list and order_number etc is assigned as a variable for each one. I am doing this in AWS Lambda

```
customer.append({'Name' : name, 'Age': age, 'Order Number': order_number, 'New Customer?': new_customer})
```

Current the output is as follows:

```
`[{'Name' : Jason, 'Age': 33, 'Order Number': 234898, 'New Customer?': Yes},{'Name' : Adrian, 'Age': 52, 'Order Number': 387253, 'New Customer?': Yes}, {'Name' : Emily, 'Age': 36, 'Order Number': 103913, 'New Customer?': No}, {'Name' : Imran, 'Age': 24, 'Order Number': 992831, 'New Customer?': No}, ...] and so on.`
```

I would like the output to be:

```
[{'Name' : Jason, 'Age': 33, 'Order Number': 234898, 'New Customer?': Yes},
{'Name' : Adrian, 'Age': 52, 'Order Number': 387253, 'New Customer?': Yes}, 
{'Name' : Emily, 'Age': 36, 'Order Number': 103913, 'New Customer?': No}, 
{'Name' : Imran, 'Age': 24, 'Order Number': 992831, 'New Customer?': No}, 
...]
```

is there a way to do this? I have tried '\n' at a few points however it isn't working as I either get a syntax error or
'EOL while scanning string literal '

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply convert entries to strings, join them with newline and print it.

```py
print('\n'.join(map(str, customer)))
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Jason', 'Age': 33, 'Order Number': 234898, 'New Customer?': 'Yes'}
{'Name': 'Adrian', 'Age': 52, 'Order Number': 387253, 'New Customer?': 'Yes'}
{'Name': 'Emily', 'Age': 36, 'Order Number': 103913, 'New Customer?': 'No'}
{'Name': 'Imran', 'Age': 24, 'Order Number': 992831, 'New Customer?': 'No'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
str(customer).replace("}, ", "}, \n")
```

Output :

```
[{'Name': 'Jason', 'Age': 33, 'Order Number': 234898, 'New Customer?': 'Yes'}, 
{'Name': 'Adrian', 'Age': 52, 'Order Number': 387253, 'New Customer?': 'Yes'}, 
{'Name': 'Emily', 'Age': 36, 'Order Number': 103913, 'New Customer?': 'No'}, 
{'Name': 'Imran', 'Age': 24, 'Order Number': 992831, 'New Customer?': 'No'}]
```